# Tilde/backtick is coming out as section/plus-minus on my external keyboard

Tags: keyboard, catalina, keybindings, karabiner

In my external keyboard only, the tilde/backtick key produces   section/plus-minus symbols. On the internal keyboard, they work fine. (Hebrew/English keyboards).

This problem has been discussed [1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284696/) [2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312488). However, the solutions do not work. I tried re-recognizing the keyboard in Settings and defining mappings in Karabiner as in the screenshot below, but these do not fix the problem.

[image: T]

Comment: Did you try the Ukelele solution??

Comment: What does pressing the topmost leftmost key produce?

Comment: Ha! The section/plus-minus key produces tilde/backticks! So, though it will require some muscle-memory, we can consider this solved. @TomGewecke please compose an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: it would be nice to map tilde/backslash to section/plus-minus and vice versa in Karabiner, but section/plus-minus is not in the list of keys offered there. Do you know how to do this ? (I could try  Ukelele to see if there is an option there, but I have Karabiner set up and would rather not mess around too much.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably find backpack/tilde on the topmost leftmost key instead of where you expect it.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m0kw6kg4zmxn6er/Hebrew%20Backtick.zip?dl=0) is a custom layout made with Ukelele which may put it back where you want it.